# Socket.io stop working after seconds, many .emit()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm doing a 2d game where connected people walk the map, so I need a quick update of where people will be.
every 17 milliseconds (17 because is 60 fps (1000/60)) I send a multidimensional array where all the characters on the map are.
The problem is that, after a few seconds that 1 person connects to the server, it (the server) simply stops sending console.log that I programmed and does nothing else, no warning appears and does not respond if you try to access it directly over the internet.
Is it an overload that it suffers? I tried to increase the delay to 500 milliseconds and even so when 2 people entered it already crash.
If it's really an overhead, what would I have to do to make my game work?

Observation: The character's move system, the client asks the server to change the character's position in the array according to the direction of the arrow.

code:

Server.js:

```
let jogadoresSala = [[]];
io.on('connection', socket=>{
//codigo que é executado quando uma pessoa conecta
    socketIds.push(socket.id);
    pessoasConectadas++;
    console.log("nova conexão : " + socket.id);
    socket.emit('voceEstaConectado', pessoasConectadas);
    socket.join('jogadores');
    if(pessoasConectadas == 1){
        jogadoresSala[0] = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 300), 
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 300), socket.id];
        setInterval(function () {
            console.log('sending..');
            io.in('jogadores').emit('sincronizacao', jogadoresSala);
        }, 17); //where is the loop
    } else {
        jogadoresSala.push([Math.floor(Math.random() * 300), 
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 300), socket.id]);
    }
}
```

cliente.js
(work for seconds, if the client does not move, it can reach within minutes);

```
socket.on('sincronizacao', posicoesPersonagens => {
    console.log(posicoesPersonagens);
    var key = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < posicoesPersonagens.length; i++) {
        personagem.setarPosicao(posicoesPersonagens[i][0], posicoesPersonagens[i][1]);
    }
})
```

picture of the game:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you have this code:

```
    setInterval(function () {
        console.log('sending..');
        io.in('jogadores').emit('sincronizacao', jogadoresSala);
    }, 17); //where is the loop
```

inside of:

```
io.on('connection', ...)
```

That means that you start a new interval that is broadcasting to all jogadores every 17ms every time the first user connects.  I know you're trying to test for doing this only on the first user, but if you go 1 user, 0 user, 1 user, 0 user, then you will start this interval multiple times.

So, for starters, you need to move the `setInterval()` outside the `io.on('connection', ...)` callback.  Just put it at the top level once your server is started.  If there are no clients connected, then it won't have anything to do because there will be no connections in the jogadores room, so no problem.

Then, 17ms (60fps) is probably too fast for a real world scenario over the internet with lots of clients.  What speed will work will depend upon your server configuration, your ISP and how many clients you expect to support with one server and you will ultimately have to understand your limits with testing at scale on your actual hardware.  Real-time client-server multi-user gaming is not a trivial endeavor.  There are lots of tricks that real-time multi-user gaming systems use to try to prevent lag and have timely updates.  Going into the details of all the things that can be done is beyond the scope of an answer here.  But, suffice it to say that you don't just power your way through it by trying to send 60fps updates to the client.  That doesn't really work.  You will need to make your user experience work at a far slower update rate.

Comment: I understand the possible bug in setInterval ().
really, if you see the latency that has just go from server to client would be 100ms, would not work I send every 17ms.
I will try to make a method that the server only passes the user's direction to the clients, and thus the clients render the user walking in one direction, when the user releases the key the server will send to all the other users that that user released the key, and thus would not render it more walking in a certain direction, do you think it will work?

Comment: @ThiagoViana - That would be one method.  You probably don't have to wait until the user completely stops walking to update other clients, you just can't be updating it as often as 17ms.

Comment: Ok, thank you, problem solved, I'll use another method.

Comment: Could you add me, in discord for example (thide # 6916)? I've applied several optimization criteria, but still the server keeps stopping working ... I'm starting to think that the error is on my computer and I need someone to test ... Please help me.